# why no rewards are appeared in solana stake account testnet?

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I have two stake accounts in the Testnet validator none of them showing any rewards is something wrong with the configuration

```
Wallet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/EjGaPZ59sycMm46VpbukVY9PnwSdPYCfeQnbRLaZaD7m?cluster=testnet
Identity : https://explorer.solana.com/address/GfudXfSxpvSBvkyNG7K1CdFhntZw3ASvBeCiTSRV5nzr?cluster=testnet
Vote: https://explorer.solana.com/address/7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt?cluster=testnet
Stake : https://explorer.solana.com/address/4EZRbSFYUQeuNCtY3Tv5tqprpTk9Ak7CZPzPsXKm1qLD?cluster=testnet
Stake2 : https://explorer.solana.com/address/967KrU4RrL2jrFtgyCKDBtyXrh3YC1SYh21PZvA6YJgE?cluster=testnet
```

When I check my vote account the rewards are there for the epoch

https://explorer.solana.com/address/7R5of8HZreWPjURAMupJuik7vx5SAGUghpwU648bWYnt?cluster=testnet

[image]

On the contrary, the stake account has not generated any rewards and they are in the Active (Delegated)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vote account has a commission of 100%, so all of the rewards go to the vote account, with nothing going to the stakers.  If you lower the commission, then your stake accounts will start to receiver rewards.

Comment: How to lower the commission ?

Comment: You can use `solana vote-update-commission <VOTE_ADDRESS> <NEW_COMMISSION> <VOTE_AUTHORIZED_WITHDRAWER>`.  More info at https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-vote-update-commission